# How to call a method from the main() that is in the same class?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, program-entry-point

I have the following situation.

I have a **Main** class in which I declared the standard **public static void main(String[] args)** method

Into the body of this **main()** method I am trying to call the following **printPdf()** declared into the **Main** class:

```
private void printPdf() {

    /** The resulting PDF file: */
    String result = "D:/SOFTLAB/massive_pdf_print.pdf";

    // STEP 1 Creazione del documento in formato A4 e senza margini:
    com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(com.itextpdf.text.PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    try {
        /* STEP 2 Constructs a PdfWriter.
                  document: The PdfDocument that has to be written.
                  os: The OutputStream the writer has to write to
         */
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(result));

        // STEP 3:
        document.open();

        // STEP 4:
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));

        // STEP 5:
        document.close();

    }catch (DocumentException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

To call it I do:

```
this.printPdf();
```

but I obtain the following error message: **'mainPkg.Main.this' cannot be referenced from a static context**

So I think that it happens because the **main()** method is a static method but how can I correctly call my **printPdf()** method (that is declared in the same **Main** class that contains the **main()**) ?

Tnx

Comment: `printPdf()` is not static method. It has to be wether you want to call it from another static method, like `main`.

Comment: @bigdestroyer: Well, no, it doesn't - the OP could create an instance of the containing class. It's far too simplistic to say that from within static methods you can only call other static methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the method `printPdf()` as `static`, or instantiate a new object of class Main, then call it from it.

Comment: Actually you would be creating a new instance of `Main`, not a new class `Main`. But otherwise, yes.

Comment: yep, instantiate a new class object = create a new instance of this class

Comment: No, you mean *instantiate a new object/instance of the class*. But this is just nitpicking. ;-)

Comment: yeah, but you're right, names are important if I want to be a competent help, corrected already